# C++ program stops after 30 minutes Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, json, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a program in C++ for a project and it seems to be giving me some issues running it on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+.
The problem is, the program is actually a countdown timer and it is not supposed to be shut down, but after only 30 minutes, the program stops working.

```
#include "led-matrix.h"
#include "graphics.h"

#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/reader.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/writer.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>


#define times 1 //numar de treceri


using namespace std;
using namespace rgb_matrix;

static int usage(const char *progname) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [options]\n", progname);
    fprintf(stderr, "Reads text from stdin and displays it. "
            "Empty string: clear screen\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Options:\n");
    rgb_matrix::PrintMatrixFlags(stderr);
    fprintf(stderr, "\t-f <font-file>    : Use given font.\n");
    return 1;
}

static int last_id = 53;

Color color(255, 255, 255);
Color color_line(255, 255, 255);
Color color_clock(255, 255, 255);
Color bg_color(0, 0, 0);

const char *bdf_font_file_text = "/home/pi/ct/fonts/9x15B.bdf";
const char *bdf_font_file_clock = "/home/pi/ct/fonts/7x13B.bdf";
const int char_width_text = 9;
const int char_width_clock = 7;
const int char_height_clock = 13;
const string def_message = "100 Pentru Viitor / RomânEști oriunde ai fi!";

int brightness = 100;
int letter_spacing = 0;
int size_of_clock;


string time_result = "";
int year = 100;
int day = 0;
int hour = 0;
int mins = 0;
int sec = 0;

double last_time_text = clock();
double last_time_clock = clock();
double last_time_db = clock();
double last_time_timer = clock();
string last_result = "";

bool countdown = false;
bool random_set = false;

int times_left = times; //numarul de treceri

rgb_matrix::Font font_text;
rgb_matrix::Font font_clock;

char remTime[16];

ofstream timeFile;

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    ((std::string *) userp)->append((char *) contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

// convert int to string (e bine sa stii de el)
static string itos(int i) {
    stringstream s;
    s << i;
    return s.str();
}

//cauta sa vada daca exista deja un timp de la care sa ii dea reset

//preia textul de la API
static string getApiText(int id) {
    if (random_set) {
        id = 0;
    }
    try {
        CURL *curl;
        std::string readBuffer;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ("http://192.168.0.108/capsula/api.php?order=ASC&id=" + itos(id)).c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2L);
            curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            Json::Value root;
            Json::Reader reader;
            bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse(readBuffer.c_str(), root);     //parse process
            if (!parsingSuccessful) {
                std::cout << "Failed to parse"
                          << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages();
                cout << readBuffer.c_str() << endl << endl;
                return def_message;
            }
            if (root[0].get("mesaj", "") != "Start Capsula-Timpului NOW") {
                if (random_set) {
                    int no = 0 + (rand() % static_cast<int>(root.size() + 1));
                    cout << "random no is " << no << endl;
                    cout << "random id is " << root[no].get("id", "").asString() << " and last_id is " << last_id
                         << endl << endl;
                    return root[no].get("mesaj", "").asString();
                } else if (!random_set) {
                    last_id = atoi(root[0].get("id", last_id).asString().c_str());
                    cout << "last_id is " << last_id << endl;
                    string result = root[0].get("mesaj", "").asString();
                    last_result = result;
                    if (result == "") {
                        random_set = true;
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        random_set = false;
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return def_message;
            }
            last_id = atoi(root[0].get("id", last_id).asString().c_str());
        }
        return def_message;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        if (last_result != "")
            return last_result;
        else return def_message;
    }
}

//aici e triggerul pt countdown
static void checkCountDownStatus() {
    try {
        CURL *curl;
        std::string readBuffer;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.108/capsula/api.php?order=ASC");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2L);
            curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            Json::Value root;
            Json::Reader reader;
            bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse(readBuffer.c_str(), root);     //parse process
            if (!parsingSuccessful) {
                std::cout << "Failed to parse"
                          << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages();
            }
            for (unsigned int no = 0; no < root.size(); no++) {
                string result = root[no].get("mesaj", "").asString();
                if (result == "Start Capsula-Timpului NOW") {
                    //if (result == "bbb") {
                    //if (result == "Porneste!") {
                    countdown = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {}
}

//aici calculeaza timpul ramas in countdown timer
static string getRemainingTime() {
    if (!countdown) { //cand nu face countdown, o sa afiseze "100:000:00:00:00"
        return "100:000:00:00:00";
    }

    //basic computation pentru countdown
    if (clock() - last_time_timer > 1301236) {
        sec--;
        if (sec < 0) {
            sec = 59;
            mins--;
        }
        if (mins < 0) {
            mins = 59;
            hour--;
        }
        if (hour < 0) {
            hour = 23;
            day--;
        }
        if (day < 0) {
            if (year % 4 == 0)
                day = 366;
            else day = 365;
            year--;
        }
        if (year < 0) {
            countdown = false;
        }

        last_time_timer = clock();
    }

    //formatare (pt estetica) a countdown-ului
    time_result = "";
    if (year < 100 && year > 10) {
        time_result = time_result + "0" + itos(year);
    } else if (year < 10) {
        time_result = time_result + "00" + itos(year);
    } else time_result = time_result + itos(year);

    time_result = time_result + ":";

    if (day < 100 && day > 10) {
        time_result = time_result + "0" + itos(day);
    } else if (day < 10) {
        time_result = time_result + "00" + itos(day);
    } else time_result = time_result + itos(day);

    time_result = time_result + ":";

    if (hour < 10) {
        time_result = time_result + "0" + itos(hour);
    } else time_result = time_result + itos(hour);

    time_result = time_result + ":";

    if (mins < 10) {
        time_result = time_result + "0" + itos(mins);
    } else time_result = time_result + itos(mins);

    time_result = time_result + ":";

    if (sec < 10) {
        time_result = time_result + "0" + itos(sec);
    } else time_result = time_result + itos(sec);

    std::ofstream out("/home/pi/ct/time.txt");
    out << time_result;
    out.close();
    return time_result;

}

//aici compara last_id cu ultimul id din baza de date
static void compareIdToDB() {
    try {
        CURL *curl;
        std::string readBuffer;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ("http://192.168.0.108/capsula/api.php?order=ASC&id=" + itos(last_id)).c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2L);
            curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            Json::Value root;
            Json::Reader reader;
            bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse(readBuffer.c_str(), root);     //parse process
            if (!parsingSuccessful) {
                std::cout << "Failed to parse" << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages();
            }
            int id = atoi(root[0].get("id", -1).asString().c_str());
            if (id > -1) {
                random_set = false;
                cout << "Found new entry" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {}
}

//aici isi face load la fonturi
static int loadFonts() {
    if (!font_text.LoadFont(bdf_font_file_text)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load text font '%s'\n", bdf_font_file_text);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!font_clock.LoadFont(bdf_font_file_clock)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load clock font '%s'\n", bdf_font_file_clock);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//aici e main-ul
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    RGBMatrix::Options matrix_options;
    rgb_matrix::RuntimeOptions runtime_opt;
    if (!rgb_matrix::ParseOptionsFromFlags(&argc, &argv, &matrix_options, &runtime_opt)) {
        return usage(argv[0]);
    }

    loadFonts();
    RGBMatrix *canvas = rgb_matrix::CreateMatrixFromOptions(matrix_options, runtime_opt);
    if (canvas == NULL)
        return 1;

    canvas->SetBrightness(brightness);
    canvas->SetPWMBits(1);

    int panel_size = 512;
    int x = panel_size;
    string remTimeString;

    string temp = getApiText(last_id);
    char line[1024];
    strncpy(line, temp.c_str(), sizeof(line));
    line[sizeof(line) - 1] = 0;

    int text_offset = (1024 - std::count(line, line + 1024, 0)) * char_width_text;
    while (true) {
        if (clock() - last_time_text > 50000) { //delay intre schimbare de pixeli
            last_time_text = clock();
            if (x > 0 - text_offset) {
                x--;
            } else {
                times_left--;
                x = panel_size;
                if (times_left <= 0) {
                    temp = getApiText(last_id);
                    strncpy(line, temp.c_str(), sizeof(line));
                    line[sizeof(line) - 1] = 0;
                    text_offset = (1024 - std::count(line, line + 1024, 0)) * char_width_text;
                    times_left = times; //numar de treceri
                }
            }
        }
        if (clock() - last_time_clock > 1301236) { //delay intre "secunde"
            remTimeString = getRemainingTime();
            size_of_clock = remTimeString.size();
            strncpy(remTime, remTimeString.c_str(), sizeof(remTime));
            last_time_clock = clock();
            if (!countdown)
                checkCountDownStatus();
        }
        if (clock() - last_time_db > CLOCKS_PER_SEC && (random_set)) { //delay intre comaparari la baza de date
            compareIdToDB();
            last_time_db = clock();
        }

        rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font_text, x, 16 + font_text.baseline(),
                             color, &bg_color, line,
                             letter_spacing);

        //draw line
        rgb_matrix::DrawLine(canvas, 0, 14, panel_size, 14, color_line);
        rgb_matrix::DrawLine(canvas, 0, 15, panel_size, 15, color_line);

        //show clock
        rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font_clock, 126 - (size_of_clock * char_width_clock) - 6, 12,
                             color_clock, &bg_color, remTime,
                             letter_spacing);
        rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font_clock, 254 - (size_of_clock * char_width_clock) - 6, 12,
                             color_clock, &bg_color, remTime,
                             letter_spacing);
        rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font_clock, 382 - (size_of_clock * char_width_clock) - 6, 12,
                             color_clock, &bg_color, remTime,
                             letter_spacing);
        rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font_clock, 510 - (size_of_clock * char_width_clock) - 6, 12,
                             color_clock, &bg_color, remTime,
                             letter_spacing);

    }
}
```

Is there any way to tell Raspbian (the OS) that it should NOT pause the process?

I'm just speaking my mind out here, honestly I have no idea what is going on.

The worst part, the problem started showing up 1 hour before the countdown is supposed to start...

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? Does it segfault? Exit cleanly? Freeze or lock up?

Comment: So the way the program works is, it gets messages from the API and scrolls each message once a matrix of leds (adafriut 32x64 led matrix) which is controlled via the raspberry GPIO pins.
What I mean by "stops working", in the *top* command, the procress is there, but the message stopped scrolling on the matrix.
I don't know how to explain better that this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help people answer your question if you remove any code not related to your question. Please review how to include a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve